# Are there any alternatives to run window services on Azure without VM?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, azure, amazon-ec2

We've developed a window service that processes Azure queue and add/update/delete database records [Only database related implementation].

Current Implementation [Running fine and there are no issues]:

Created a window service
Deployed on Azure VM

And we are trying to find out better alternatives that helps to deploy our business implementation [currently wrapped as Window Service] into Azure Website and/or Azure Cloud Service.

One Possible Alternative:

1. Create an ASP.NET Mvc website
2. Create 3 Actions

   a. Start [Starts a static timer]

   b. Stop [Stops a static timer]

   c. Execute [Called through WebRequest on Timer Elapsed]
3. Deploy that site on Azure website.

1) Have you ever implemented above alternative on Cloud [Azure/Amazon or other]?

2) If yes, would like to know problems faced and their workaround/solutions.

3) Are there better alternatives?

4) Is Window Service best solution in the current scenario?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, what does an NT service do? It starts at system startup and runs some kind of infinite loop to "listen" for something or to process some stuff it knows where to fetch from.

Worker roles (and web roles too - those are actually worker roles with IIS) do just the same - Azure infrastructure starts them (and restarts if they fail), then `RoleEntryPoint.OnStart()` is invoked for initialization and then `RoleEntryPoint.Run()` is invoked and the latter should either sleep forever or run an infinite loop. Basically it's just the same as an NT service, the difference is the NT service is bound to a specific machine and the worker/web role is bound to a "deployment" - a combination of code to execute and settings for that code.

Answer (score 1):

Use worker roles, service bus and cloud services. It's a more robust implementation and in provides APIs for what you are looking for. Check [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazure/archive/2013/01/14/the-right-way-to-handle-azure-onstop-events.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Azure WebJobs are also an alternative to both Windows Services on a VM and Worker Roles in Cloud Services

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/videos/azure-webjobs-basics/